# Best way to define "conditional" aliases in shell

Tags: bash, shell, alias, zsh

What's the best way to define an alias if, let's say, "ag" executable is found?

```
if (( $+commands[ag] )) ; then alias grep='ag'; fi
```

or

```
[[ -s $(which ag) ]] && alias grep='ag'
```

or

```
if $(which ag >& /dev/null); then alias grep='ag'; fi
```

or ...?

By best, I mean more robust, more performant and/or more portable (Bash, Zsh).

What's your advice?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't see how the simple obvious POSIX variant would have any drawbacks compared to the (mostly non-portable) alternatives you propose.

```
type ag >/dev/null 2>&1 && alias grep=ag
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Basically answering my question.

Comment: Side question: better to use ```type ag >& /dev/null``` or simply ```type ag > /dev/null``` (as you do)?

Comment: The former is not portable. If you want to redirect stderr, that's `2>/dev/null` or `>/dev/null 2>&1` for both stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 1):

I use this `pathto` function for portability to all Bourne heritage shells (I don't use `which` because it is not in POSIX so its output format is unspecified and it complains when nothing is found instead of being silent):

```
pathto () {
        DIRLIST=`echo $PATH|tr : ' '`
        for e in "$@"; do
                for d in $DIRLIST; do
                        test -f "$d/$e" -a -x "$d/$e" && echo "$d/$e"
                done
        done
}
```

which echos the pathname for any executable given when found, along with

```
test "`pathto less`" != "" && alias more=less
```

As for performance, you shouldn't care because the number of times you call `pathto` is negligible. Your first two examples use the non-portable `(( ))` and `[[ ]]` constructs and should be avoided.

Note also that I don't specifically deal with empty parts in `PATH`. For security reasons they should be avoided, just like `.`.

Comment: This is unreliable if any entries in `$PATH` contain spaces. But fixing that in array-less (and `<(...)`-less) Bourne shells would require some work (though keeping `echo` as output means you could use this with a normal pipe and assuming `printf` that can output `'\0'` you could do it... I think). Also this *does*, in a way, deal with empty `$PATH` values since it ignores them entirely as they get dropped in the `for d in $DIRLIST` loop. That said it does that in a way that means it will miss the fact that the shell itself will see a command in the current directory.

Comment: This also uses the deprecated `-a` argument to `test` and can't be used with more than one command if the command name itself contains a space (ignoring the `$PATH`-with-spaces issue). (And yes, I seriously doubt this is an issue that will ever come up but figured it was worth mentioning anyway.)

Comment: @EtanReisner Your pedantry is appreciated, thanks! :-) Merry Christmas.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for commenting on the portability of my examples!

Comment: When you want the test to be silent if the executable is not found (so, when you can't use `type`), what you would use (because you say that `which`is no good)?

Comment: @user3341592 I would use my pathto function. I implemented it because there is no standard utility that behaves the way I want.